AnalysisException due to mismatched datatypes using array_contains()
I am getting an "AnalysisException with the following:
df = df.where(array_contains(col("row_id"), 0)

AnalysisExeption: cannot resolve 'array_contains(row_id, 0)' due to data type mismatch: Input to function array_contains should have been array followed by a value with same element type, but it's [Bigint, int].;

So I change the datatype:
df.select(col("row_id").cast("int").alias("row_id")
df = df.where(array_contains(col("row_id"), 0)

Then I get the following error:
AnalysisExeption: cannot resolve 'array_contains(row_id, 0)' due to data type mismatch: Input to function array_contains should have been array followed by a value with same element type, but it's [int, int].;

What do I need to change?
For example I have:

This is what I'd like to end up with:


row_id should be array of integer and not the simple int. Please show your sample data.

@Emma: "row_id" is a just a column of integers (0, 1, 2, 3 ... etc.) that represents the index of the table I'm trying to modify. Doesn't that qualify as an array? (Basically, I'm just trying to omit the first two rows of a Spark data frame.)

dataframe's data type is for what you have in a cell. It seems you have integer for row_id. You can confirm this by df.printSchema().  As for what you are trying to do, it is not clear to me yet. Could you post your sample data and expected result?

@Emma, please take a look at the before and after transformation of my Spark data frame that I'd like to achieve. On the bottom of the question.

This operation is called filter. Please check https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter.html
